# Application not install on real CarPlay device

Tags: ios, carplay

I add CarPlay integration to my music application. 
 When I testing my application/CarPlay on simulator all work is fine, but on real device nothing to show. Application Icon not show. Can anybody help me to fix it problem or give me idea how to fix it or what is a reason?

[image]
Add com.apple.developer.playable-content 
to entitlements. Also when try to launch app on device I got a message error

Answer (score 1):

To run an app on device (and CarPlay system), you need to add a capability to your provisioning profile (CarPlay entitlement). To do that contact to Apple here  https://developer.apple.com//contact/carplay/ because CarPlay system allow only some kinds of apps (audio is one of them).

> The CarPlay framework is for use by navigation apps only. If you want to add CarPlay support to your audio app, use MPPlayableContentManager. For messaging apps, use SiriKit’s Messaging-related intents to support reading and sending messages in CarPlay through Siri. For VoIP calling apps, use CallKit with SiriKit’s VoIP Calling-related intents to make and answer audio calls on a CarPlay system.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/carplay/overview/introduction/

P.S. Documentation says than CarPlay framework is only for navigation apps, but all CarPlay interface is in that framework. So how can we build audio app with MPPlayableContentManager without CarPlay framework?

Comment: For exaple i already have accept from Apple - "We have assigned the CarPlay audio app entitlement to your Apple Developer account." But where i should find CarPlay?