# MyApp not show in CarPlay

Tags: ios, xcode, carplay

I like create Communication application for CarPlay.
But I have a problem with implementation.

MyApp.entitlements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.carplay-calling</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.carplay-communication</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.siri</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

info plist:

```
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
<key>CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                    <string>CPTemplateApplicationScene</string>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>TemplateSceneConfiguration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).CarPlaySceneDelegate</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>                         
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>Main</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

This code is never calls:

```
import CarPlay
class CarPlaySceneDelegate: UIResponder, CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate {
    var interfaceController: CPInterfaceController?
    func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene,
                                  didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
        self.interfaceController = interfaceController
        let contact = CPContact(name: "TEST", image: UIImage(systemName: "person")!)
        let tamplate = CPContactTemplate(contact: contact)
        interfaceController.setRootTemplate(tamplate, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didDisconnectInterfaceController interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
        self.interfaceController = nil
    }
}
```

I have a valid provisioning profile.

I create Provisioning Profile with CarPlay Comminication Entitlements.

Please what am i doing wrong?

If use this bundle: "com.example.apple-samplecode.CoastalRoads" all works.

Well thank you

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/58930911/95309 ?

Comment: Apple has created new Entitlements for iOS14, com.apple.developer.carplay-communication. I request for this entitlemnet. And cerate profile with this entitlement in developer portal.

Comment: @Alino do you want to post your findings as an answer?

Comment: @fruitcoder yes, you must implement siri for example - INStartAudioCallIntent, INStartCallIntent, INSearchCallHistoryIntent for comunication call app.